# PowerPoint VBA - way to put Tag on Cell to identify

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm trying to test automation capability of MS PowerPoint using VBA.

For my requirement, any table cell MUST be marked by controlled ID and referred back by using this ID. However, I couldn't fint the appropriate way.
Do you have any idea?

```
  Dim slide As slide
  Dim t As Table
  Dim r As Integer
  Dim c As Integer
  Dim s As Shape
  Set slide = Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
  Set t = slide.Shapes(1).Table
  Set s = t.Cell(1, 1).Shape
  ' t.Tags and s.Tags aren't accessible...
  ' Is there any way to put ID into the Cell or Shape of Cell?
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably post this question in StackOverflow rather than here; SuperUser is devoted to "How to use this program" questions, StackOverflow to "How do I program this" queries.

One way you might approach this is to store the tag data for the table in an array, then convert the array into a string something like this:

Row1Cell1Value|Row1Cell2Value|...|Row1CellNValue~Row2Cell1Value|Row2Cell2Value|...|Row2CellNValue and so on, where | is the separator between tag values for each cell in the array and ~ is the separator between rows.

Add this string as a tag on the SLIDE where the table resides, eg:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Tags.Add TableName, BigOldStringOfTags
```

When you need to retrieve the table's tags, you'd retrieve this big string, SPLIT it on ~ to create an array of strings, each element of which represents a row of tags for the corresponding row of the table.  You could then split *that* element to get the individual tags for each cell in the row.

Depending on your needs, it might be conceptually easier to do this doublesplit trick to rebuild the original array of tags, so that each (x,y) element of the array corresponds to the same (row,col) cell of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks, Steve, and sorry for my slow response.
I've already tried as same approach you've recommended. However unfortunately, it doesn't fit to variable tables.
That is, the tag information on the top level table will be invalidated when an end user inserts/removes/reorders rows/columuns because this information essentially depends on indexes of row/columun at design time.
According to the requirement, we need an approach which has rational redundancy against the modification of the table. The easiest way is to tag for each table cells I suppose, but I couldn't find a nice implementation way. Do you have any good ideas?
I wii also post on StackOverflow, than you for your advice!